# How do I set button font to Marlett

Tags: c#, winforms, button, fonts, truetype

I'm attempting to set a font of button to system's Marlett font. However, though I manually set the font-face, other font is used. Also, Marlett is not listed, when I use the font dialog to choose a font for that button.

Why is it so? What can I do to use Marlett font in .NET Windows Forms controls?

Comment: Is the font installed on the machine?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive it is.

Comment: OK, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191751/edit) the question and add the code you're using to set the `Font`.

Comment: There is no code. I'm trying to do it from the Windows Forms Designer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though I do not know what code is behind the designer, I have always found that custom installed fonts **do not** show up in the designer. The good news is that the `Font` property is ambient so if you wanted all controls to have the same `Font` you would **only** have to set it at the `Form`. However, it seems like you just want one control to have the `Font` so let's do this:

```
ctrl.Font = new Font("Marlett", 8.5f);
```

which will set that control's `Font` to `Marlett` and a size of `8.5` for example.

If you wanted an entire set of controls to have the same `Font`, **if they can be placed in a container like a `Panel`**, then you would only have to set the `Font` of the `Panel`; because again, it's an ambient property.

Comment: Marlett is a builtin font with glyphs like minimize, maximize, close, scrollbar arrows etc. Designer fails to set it properly (even if I force it to, manually entering the font name), but your solution from the code actually works. Thanks!

Comment: @Spook, I'm really glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 4):

```
   button1.Font = new Font("Marlett",8, FontStyle.Regular);
```

put this code for your button name Button1 , where you want change  ( in from constrcutor after iinitializecomponet or in form Load  event )

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that the designer by default wants to set the GdiCharSet to 0. This causes the Marlett font to fall back to another font.

If you change the GdiCharSet to 1 it will render normally.

Also note the changes it makes in the .designer.cs, this will also explain why it did work when you would set the font manually from code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what finally worked for me.

```
ctrl.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Marlett", 12f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(1)));
```

The last ((byte)(1)) sets the GdiCharSet to 1, which @Paul noted in one of the other answers.